# Convert SOQL Query to SOSL

Tags: soql, sosl

I have a Query

```
query = 'Select Id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact  where (Id = ' + cstIdsList + ') ;' + 'Select Id, Name, Primary_Email__c, Phone  from Account where (Id = ' + astIdsList + ') and (RecordType.Name <>  \'Household\') ';
```

Changing it to SOSL

```
FIND {map*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact  (Id, Name, Email, Phone), Account  (Id, Name, Primary_Email__c, Phone)
```

Where do i add the cstIdsList for Contact and astIdsList for Account seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Place the WHERE Immediately after the field list:

```
FIND :value 
IN ALL FIELDS
RETURNING Contact (Id, Name, Email, Phone WHERE Id = :cstIdsList),
          Account (Id, Name, Primary_Email__c, Phone WHERE Id = :astIdsList)
```

Comment: FIND :value 
IN ALL FIELDS
RETURNING Contact (Id, Name, Email, Phone WHERE FirstName = firstName, MiddleName = middleName, LastName = lastName),
          Account (Id, Name, Primary_Email__c, Phone WHERE Id = :astIdsList)

Comment: @SamuelJackson If you need multiple filters, use AND instead of commas.

Answer (score 0):

But i have a strange requirement.
I have to pull 2 different search results. 
1 is Exact Match (Works well with AND)
2 is Like Search Results.

Second one is like the below in Dev Console using Text.
Search results have to show all the similar results.
Like test1, test2, test3 and everything which has test.
How can i do it with Variables??

```
FIND { test} 
IN All Fields 
RETURNING Contact (Id, Name, Email, Phone where  FirstName LIKE '%test%' OR MiddleName LIKE '%test%' OR LastName LIKE '%test%' )
```